# Gawk not working correctly in finding min between 3 lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh, gawk

I have the following gawk script:

```
BEGIN{
    count = 0
    imp = ""
    time = 0
}

{

    if(count==0){
        imp = $0
        time = $7
        count = 1
    }

    else if(count==1 || count==2){

        if($7 < time){
            imp = $0
            time = $7
        }

            count+=1

    }

    else{
        count=0
        print imp
    }

}
```

and a bunch of files like this:

```
1 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.784696 0.114561 0.670135
1 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.783619 0.114349 0.669270
1 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.725526 0.114805 0.610721
2 57 0.850000 0.000010 1.590584 0.102643 1.487942
2 57 0.850000 0.000010 1.291972 0.076006 1.215967
2 57 0.850000 0.000010 1.224136 0.063005 1.161131
4 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.679327 0.062899 0.616428
4 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.680867 0.062456 0.618411
4 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.684800 0.063411 0.621389
8 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.374985 0.063619 0.311367
8 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.401494 0.062838 0.338655
8 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.405216 0.064353 0.340862
12 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.317534 0.063243 0.254290
12 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.317531 0.063118 0.254413
12 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.318544 0.063321 0.255222
16 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.379314 0.063865 0.315448
16 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.382251 0.064108 0.318144
16 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.381444 0.063148 0.318296
20 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.333159 0.063614 0.269545
20 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.336454 0.063309 0.273144
20 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.333363 0.063646 0.269717
24 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.589092 0.066359 0.522733
24 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.429424 0.066578 0.362845
24 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.335697 0.068287 0.267411
1 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.793457 0.060388 0.733069
1 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.791233 0.060041 0.731192
1 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.789624 0.060151 0.729474
2 100 0.850000 0.000000 2.140322 0.063280 2.077041
2 100 0.850000 0.000000 2.104924 0.063320 2.041604
2 100 0.850000 0.000000 2.110660 0.063040 2.047621
4 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.145730 0.063037 1.082693
4 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.139739 0.062964 1.076775
4 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.141787 0.063186 1.078601
8 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.656741 0.063040 0.593701
8 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.660081 0.063351 0.596730
8 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.659872 0.063350 0.596522
12 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.511580 0.063247 0.448333
12 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.509540 0.063253 0.446287
12 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.503905 0.062864 0.441041
16 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.613314 0.063025 0.550289
16 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.619024 0.063526 0.555498
16 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.622365 0.063735 0.558631
20 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.590244 0.063859 0.526385
20 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.537661 0.063859 0.473802
20 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.531875 0.063343 0.468532
24 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.484166 0.066820 0.417346
24 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.694105 0.069127 0.624978
24 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.569517 0.070212 1.499304
```

The rows [1,3], [4,6], [7,9] etc. they have always the same $1 and all the other columns are different.
And i want the entire row with the minimum value of the last column and exclude the other 2 but this script that I did is now working properly.

So the result wold be:

```
1 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.725526 0.114805 0.610721
2 57 0.850000 0.000010 1.224136 0.063005 1.161131
4 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.679327 0.062899 0.616428
8 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.374985 0.063619 0.311367
12 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.317534 0.063243 0.254290
16 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.379314 0.063865 0.315448
20 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.333159 0.063614 0.269545
24 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.335697 0.068287 0.267411
1 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.789624 0.060151 0.729474
2 100 0.850000 0.000000 2.104924 0.063320 2.041604
4 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.139739 0.062964 1.076775
8 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.656741 0.063040 0.593701
12 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.503905 0.062864 0.441041
16 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.613314 0.063025 0.550289
20 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.531875 0.063343 0.468532
24 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.484166 0.066820 0.417346
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your input and output examples in question, this one-liner does the job:

```
awk 'NR%3==1{if(a)print a;a=$0;v=$NF;next}$NF<v{a=$0;v=$NF}END{print a}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
else{
    count=0
    print imp
}
```

to:

```
else{
    print imp

    imp = $0
    time = $7
    count=1
}
```

I'm now getting:

```
1 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.725526 0.114805 0.610721
2 57 0.850000 0.000010 1.224136 0.063005 1.161131
4 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.679327 0.062899 0.616428
8 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.374985 0.063619 0.311367
12 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.317534 0.063243 0.254290
16 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.379314 0.063865 0.315448
20 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.333159 0.063614 0.269545
24 57 0.850000 0.000010 0.335697 0.068287 0.267411
1 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.789624 0.060151 0.729474
2 100 0.850000 0.000000 2.104924 0.063320 2.041604
4 100 0.850000 0.000000 1.139739 0.062964 1.076775
8 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.656741 0.063040 0.593701
12 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.503905 0.062864 0.441041
16 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.613314 0.063025 0.550289
20 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.531875 0.063343 0.468532
24 100 0.850000 0.000000 0.484166 0.066820 0.417346
```